# How to Use DropDown Selected Vaue as Parameter for Filter in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-filters

Iam Using Select2 Drop down  which is not Filter on Select :-

My Code :-

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                            jQuery(document).ready(function($)
                                            {
                                                $("#select-res").select2();
                                        </script>
                                    <select class="form-control select" ng-model="displayName"  id="select-res">
                                        <option data-ng-repeat="objin objs" value="{{obj.displayName}}">{{obj.displayName}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <script>
                                        $('#select-res').select2().on('change', function(e) {
                                          var selectedval= $(this).val();
                                           alert(selectedval);
                                           // $("#filterselected").html(selectedval);
                                           // $("#filterselected").val(selectedval+' ');
                                            document.getElementById("filterselected").value = selectedval;
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                      <input id="filterselected" type="text" ng-model="displayName" />
                                </div>
```

I used data-ng-model="displayName" for Two Way Binding

Filter Code :-

```
<div data-ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:displayname" >
       Results ....
</div>
```

The Options i Selected in Select2 Drop Down Is Not Being Input For Filter Parameter .

I have written the Selected Value in to a Text Box With  data binding as ng-model ="displayName"  but Not Filtering :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using select2 library with you should use it angular version which [**`ui-select2`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)

Which provides better binding while dealing with angular scope. As you want to bind change event here you could simply use `ng-change` angular native directive.

**Markup**

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="number" data-placeholder="Pick a number" ng-change="changeSelect()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="one">First</option>
    <option value="two">Second</option>
    <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could You Please Send me Some reference Url for ui-select2 .

Comment: @PRASAD look at this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4spbdn?p=info & this is github link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: One Question Would it Support Update Operation .. I mean  When the Values Selected at the @ Post Operation Would Show as Selected when Edited Right Or Do we need some Coding Magic ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76823/discussion-between-prasad-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: HI Pankaj I just Posted the Link in Our discussion Window Please take a Look

Comment: @PRASAD what that link contains?

Answer (score 1):

Trouble can be, that jquery widgets can append additional input elements breaking angular linking. If so i can suggest 2 solutions to try:

1. use angular-ui/ui-select  instead select2
2. if you refuse it somewhat,  use angular scopes  $apply  method to let angular know that something changed.  I don't know if your piece of html is under controller, if yes you can just call `$apply("displayName = '"+selectedval+"'")` in your `onchange` handler

there could also be many other causes,  for example form and filter is on different scopes

Comment: Could You Please Send me Some reference Url for ui-select2 .

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/Getting-Started